# Tag synonym suggestion: [windows-domain] -> [active-directory]

Tags: discussion

I noticed [a question](https://serverfault.com/q/347532/9770) that was heavily concerned with Active Directory that did not have the [active-directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/active-directory) tag but rather used the [windows-domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-domain) tag. As of this moment there are 382 questions tagged with windows-domain and 2,361 with active directory.

[I've proposed a tag synonym](https://serverfault.com/tags/active-directory/synonyms) from [windows-domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-domain) to [active-directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/active-directory).

Is there ever a time when the concept of a domain within active directory should be tagged separately from [active-directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/active-directory)? And if so, wouldn't it be better to keep the tag symmetry by naming it [active-directory-domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/active-directory-domain) which would leave open the possibility of [active-directory-forrest](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/active-directory-forrest) and [active-directory-site](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/active-directory-site)?

---

### EDIT 1: NT Domains

As John Gardeniers points out in the comments, NT4 domains are likely to still exist even in 2012, and that is *not* Active Directory.

New Suggest: All NT4 domain related posts should be tagged with something that clarifies that it's NT4. How about [nt4-domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/nt4-domain)? Of course, this then means that the [windows-domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-domain) posts would need to be winnowed for which ones are referring to NT4 and which are truly referring to AD.

Comment: Windows Domain != Active Directory. There are still people running NT systems. Perhaps they shouldn't be but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Yes, that's what I was thinking too. Updated my answer.

Comment: Also Samba is effectively NT4 domains (Samba 4 is effectively AD), but those questions tend to be tagged as such.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the newest 50 questions with the [windows-domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/windows-domain) tag, they are all about AD domains with the exception of [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/290188), which is about Samba.

While there surely would be cases where a question only concerns the actual directory service (e.g. something about the schema, an object type or an attribute value) most questions are the much broader case of *want-to-get-things-done-with-my-Windows-Server-no-matter-how*.

I am not sure about the actual tagging policy at Serverfault (does each and every corner case get an own tag?), but I think a merger would not hurt as the merged tag still would fulfil the general purpose of grouping similar questions with the added benefit of more eyes reading them ([active-directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/active-directory) has way more followers).

Comment: I don't think questions about AD-the-service are really distinct from AD-the-domain-entity -- in either case as you pointed out `HALP! MAH AD SERVICE IS B0RKED AND WONT START!!` and `HALP! HOW IS AD SCHEMA EXTENDEDED?` are both questions about the same family of things so I think grouping them makes sense.